# Get unique ID for inserted SIM Card

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier, sim-card, android-10.0

I am trying to save SIM Cards history in the android application,

I am using `mTelephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber()` to get SIM unique id which is working perfectly but not in **Android 10** because of `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission restrictions,

Is there any other way to get a unique id for every SIM which will work in Android 10 as well?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, that's the whole point of the new restrictions in Android 10: that apps shouldn't be able to obtain unique hardware identifiers.

Comment: As per the document, you should avoid using hardware identifiers. Use this document https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Answer (score 1):

I am also having same problem but I want only one uniqueID. I am using getImei() method for it. But it Requires android.Manifest.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE. I am using it for Android 8.You can check here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager?hl=en#getImei(int)
Please inform if it works for Android 10 real device or not

```
mTelephonyManager.getImei()
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/highlights#privacy_for_users
Please read this

Comment: Thank you. You save me before uploading build to Play store